# Problem using data passed by localStorage in a counter

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, counter, game-development

I´m trying to make a counter of days, pass that to another page with localStorage and then keep counting them when they click a button, the info reaches the other page, shows me the previous number of days without a problem but when i try to keep increasing the days goes back to 0 without taking into account the number that i passed initially, thanks for the help.

```
//first page
body>
    <button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
    
    <a href="pruebaCounter.html">
    <button onClick="hacerCosa()">Beach</button><br />
    </a>
    
    <script>
        var d = localStorage.getItem("d");
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = d;
        
        localStorage.clear();
     var clicks = 0;

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    var d = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
        localStorage.setItem('d', d);
};
        
        function hacerCosa(){
            var d = document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML;
        localStorage.setItem('d', d);
        }
    </script>

//second page
<body>
    <button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
    <script>
        var d = localStorage.getItem("d");
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = d;
        
        localStorage.clear();
     var clicks = 0;

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
    </script>
</body>

//Solution going both ways, thanks for the help
//first page
<body>
    <button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
    
    <a href="pruebaCounter.html">
    <button onClick="hacerCosa()">Beach</button><br />
    </a>
    
    <script>
        if (localStorage.getItem("d") !== null){
        var d = localStorage.getItem("d");
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = d;
        
        localStorage.clear();
     var clicks = parseInt(d);
        } else {
            var clicks = 0;
        }

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    var d = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
        localStorage.setItem('d', d);
};
        
        function hacerCosa(){
            var d = document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML;
        localStorage.setItem('d', d);
        }
    </script>
</body>
//second page
<body>
    <button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
    
    <a href="pruebaCounter2.html">
    <button onClick="hacerCosa()">cave</button><br />
    </a>
    <script>
        if (localStorage.getItem("d") !== null){
        var d = localStorage.getItem("d");
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = d;
        
        localStorage.clear();
     var clicks = parseInt(d);
        } else {
            var clicks = 0;
        }

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
        
         function hacerCosa(){
            var d = document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML;
        localStorage.setItem('d', d);
        }
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: You set it to zero.

Comment: Typo?  Did you mean to initialize `var clicks = d;` on the second page?  (Or perhaps something like `var clicks = parseInt(d);`?)  I would expect `var clicks = 0;` to initially equal `0`...

Comment: thank you for your help, it was that, i thought about it when the counter function was more complex and when i simplified it i discarded it as the problem, if someone is looking at this in the future this solves the problem but if you want it to go both ways put a conditional to verify if the localStorage is empty before var clicks = parseInt(d); if not the click counter gives NaN back if localStorage is empty, very happy with the help and the speed of the answers.